# Добавить фоновую музыку в 2д платформере

Tags: python, pygame, arcade

Как добавить фоновую музыку в 2д платформере?

Я  пишу игру через python, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

В библиотеке *PyGame* есть встроенный способ воспроизведения фоновой музыки.

Для этого импортируйте `mixer` из модуля `pygame`:

`from pygame import mixer`

Далее используйте `music = pygame.mixer.music.load('путь/к/файлу')`, чтобы загрузить файл с музыкой.

И `pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)`, чтобы воспроизвести музыку фоном.

Официальная документация по `pygame.mixer`: [клик](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html)

Answer (score 0):

загружаете через `pygame.mixer.music.load(*имяФайла*)` и пишете `pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)`

Comment: а как добавить через библиотеку arcade?

Comment: я не знаю. Если вам нужно через какую то конкретную библиотеку, пишите все эти детали в вопросе